# Variable is giving different values in different areas of the script (and when accessed in other scripts) and not updating the value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a tower defense game and everytime I summon an enemy, i add 1 to the **enemyCount** variable. and everytime the enemy reaches the endpoint, I subtract 1 to the same variable. Default value is zero.

For some reason the variable gives different values in different parts of the script. I have 2 other scripts that has access to **enemyCount**. One is the *PlayerUI* script which just displays it, and the other is the *enemyMovement* script which is suppose to subtract 1 to it everytime the enemy object is destroyed.

The value of **enemyCount** in *PlayerUI* is 0, and it updates when the subtraction happens so it becomes -1.

Now when i run the game again, it retains the value of -1, and when subtracted to -2, its -2 that is displayed on the next run.

The value of **enemyCount** when I log it in the update function inside the script is that it updates to +1 when the enemy is summoned but doesnt update when the enemy is destroyed.

Can anyone point out what i did wrong?

**WaveSpawner script:**

```
public Transform enemyPrefab;
private Transform[] spawners;

private bool summonWave = false;
private float countDown = 2;
private int enemyPerWave = 1;
private int waveCtr = 0;
private int enemyCount;

void Awake() {
    spawners = new Transform[transform.childCount];

    for (var i = 0; i < spawners.Length; i++) {
        spawners[i] = transform.GetChild(i);
    }
}

void Start() {
    enemyCount = 0;
}

void Update() {
    
    if(countDown <= 0) {
        summonWave = true;
        countDown = 999;
    }

    if (summonWave) {
        StartCoroutine(waveSpawner());
    }else {
        countDown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    Debug.Log(enemyCount);          //GIVES THE RIGHT VALUE BUT DOESNT SUBTRACT 1 WHEN ENEMY IS DESTROYED
}

public int getEnemyCount() {            //Accessed by the PlayerUI script. just to display it onscreen.
    Debug.Log(enemyCount);              // GIVES A VALUE OF N-1
    return enemyCount;
}

public void reduceEnemyCount() {        //Accessed by the EnemyMovement script.
    enemyCount--;                       //IF THE ENEMY REACHES THE END, THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED AND THEN THE ENEMY OBJECT IS DESTROYED
}

IEnumerator waveSpawner() {
    waveCtr++;
    summonWave = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyPerWave; i++) {
        summonEnemies();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
    }
}

void summonEnemies() {
    enemyCount += 1;            //ADDS 1 TO THE VARIABLE EVERY TIME I SPAWN AN ENEMY UNIT. IN THIS CASE JUST 1

    Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawners[0].position, spawners[0].rotation);
    //Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawners[1].position, spawners[1].rotation);
    //Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawners[2].position, spawners[2].rotation);
    //Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawners[3].position, spawners[3].rotation);
}
```

}

**EnemyMovement script:**

```
public WaveSpawner spawner;

private float speed = 35f;
private int numberOfCycles = 2;

private Transform target;
private Transform startingPoint;
private int cycleCtr = 0;

private bool isDestroyed;

void Start() {
    target = getClosestWaypoint(Waypoints.points);
    startingPoint = target;

    isDestroyed = false;
}

void Update() {

    Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
    transform.Translate(dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) <= 0.2f && !isDestroyed) {
        if (cycleCtr == numberOfCycles) {
            spawner.reduceEnemyCount();         //subtracts the enemyCount in WaveSpawner
            isDestroyed = true;
            Destroy(gameObject);                            //destroying the enemy unit   
        } else {
            if (target.name == startingPoint.name) {
                cycleCtr++;
            }
            target = getToNextWaypoint(target);
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayerUI script:**

```
public Text enemyCount_UI;

[SerializeField]
private WaveSpawner spawner;

private int enemyCount_var;

void Start() {
    enemyCount_UI.text = "Enemy count: 0";
    enemyCount_var = 0;
}

void Update() {
    enemyCount_var = spawner.getEnemyCount();

    enemyCount_UI.text = "Enemy count: " + enemyCount_var.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing from `StartCoroutine` that you have multiple threads reading/writing to the variable? You obviously have no atomic/critical section handling in your code.

Comment: @Brannon do not mistaken the OP. `StartCoroutine` does not create another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you have assigned `WaveSpawner` prefab to `EnemyMovement` prefab and `PlayerUI` object. And you also probably have instance of `WaveSpawner` added somewhere in the scene.

Let's call `WaveSpawner` (from prefab) a `PrefabSpawner` and `WaveSpawner` (from scene) a `SceneSpawner`. When game is started, `SceneSpawner` is created. It has its own value of enemy count. When you spawn a prefab of `EnemyMovement` it is referencing `PrefabSpawner`, not `SceneSpawner`. What happens, is that `SceneSpawner` always incremets its own enemyCount, while `EnemyMovement` decreases count on `PrefabSpawner`. Because `PlayerUI` is also accessing `PrefabSpawner` it sees its value instead of `SceneSpawner`.

Try changing the spawning to this:

```
void summonEnemies() {
    enemyCount += 1;            //ADDS 1 TO THE VARIABLE EVERY TIME I SPAWN AN ENEMY UNIT. IN THIS CASE JUST 1

    var enemyInstnace = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawners[0].position, spawners[0].rotation);
    enemyInstance.spawner = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having WaveSpawner script on both PlayerUI and EnemyMovement, you'll want to make sure they are accessing the **same** instance of the script.

If you haven't already, create an empty game object to be your "wave spawner" in the scene and drop the WaveSpawner script on that.

Then update PlayerUI and EnemyMovement to get a reference to that game object, and then its WaveSpawner script

```
public Text enemyCount_UI;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject waveSpawnerGameObject;
private WaveSpawner spawner;

private int enemyCount_var;

void Start() {
    enemyCount_UI.text = "Enemy count: 0";
    enemyCount_var = 0;
}
void Awake()
{
    // Get the reference here
    spawner = waveSpawnerGameObject.GetComponent<WaveSpawner>();
}

void Update() {
    enemyCount_var = spawner.getEnemyCount();

    enemyCount_UI.text = "Enemy count: " + enemyCount_var.ToString();
}
```

And do the same for your enemy movement and enemy prefabs